# STM32F0x1 run SYSCLK at 1MHz with 8 MHz external crystal

Tags: stm32, clock-speed

I am using hardware with an 8 MHz external crystal and would like to reduce the SYSCLK frequency to 1MHz. I haven't been able to do this yet. Is it possible to achieve this with certain PLL and DIV settings?

Comment: What's the importance of a 1 MHz SYSCLK?

Comment: He means probably the core clock

Comment: @Colin__s OP's lost interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, according to the datasheet the output from the PLL must be between 16 and 48 MHz and there's no way to put an external crystal through a divider before reaching the sysclk (see the clock tree on page 14 of the datasheet).

Comment: Can the downvoter please say what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Not sure either. Answer looks correct to me. Have an up vote.

Answer (score -2):

Of course it is possible.

Here is the configuration for F031c6

[image]

Comment: This is wrong. The OP asks for a 1MHz SYSCLK, your picture shows a 16MHz SYSCLK.

Comment: I bet he means the core clock